# LCOM4 interrogation about way to calculate

Tags: algorithm, oop, metrics, code-metrics, lcom

Recently, I encountered a sementic issue in the way of calculating the LCOM4, a metric used to find how the methods and the properties of a class are cohersive.

## Introduction

LCOM4 is "the 4th method of calculating the Lack in Cohesion Of Methods", and has been described by Hitz and Montazeri (http://www.isys.uni-klu.ac.at/PDF/1995-0043-MHBM.pdf) and is currently the best way to define how many responsabilities a class own.

I'll try to not use a specific development language because my question is for all OOP languages.

Let me basically explain how it works to people who doesn't know, with a default algorithm:

```
Class Foo {
    property a,b

    function f1() { this.a = 1 }
    function f2() { this.f1() }
    function f3() { this.b = 3 }
}
```

This class have two flows:

- attribute a is shared by f1() and f2()
- attribute b is shared by f3()

So the LCOM4 of Foo is 2.

Let's change for example the function f2() to also share the property b.

```
Class Foo {
    property a,b

    function f1() { this.a = 1 }
    function f2() { this.f1(); this.b = 1 }
    function f3() { this.b = 3 }
}
```

Now this class only have one flow:

- both attributes a and b are shared by f1(), f2() and f3().

This means the LCOM4 of Foo is now 1.

LCOM4 = 0 or LCOM4 = 1 means the class has none or only 1 responsability, which is what every developer must want for their classes, as they respect the **S** of the **S**OLID good practices.

You can find more information with graphs here: http://www.aivosto.com/project/help/pm-oo-cohesion.html#LCOM4

## My question

Let's imagine you wrote a class like this one:

```
Class Bar {
    property a

    static function build() { return new self }
    function Bar() { this.a = 5 }
}
```

...and of course, when doing `new self`, I create a new instance of Bar built using the method `Bar` declared.

Based on the Hitz and Montazeri works, what is the LCOM4 of my class `Bar`?

Lots of metrics tools I use are saying LCOM4=2, but to me, the class only have 1 responsability and so its LCOM4 must be 1.
Also, even if it's not really explicit, both methods `build()` and `Bar()` must belongs to the same graph of functions as `build()` is calling `Bar()` (well, I know, it's calling upon another instance, but even if it's not the same object, it's the same class).

What is your opinion on this?

Does anyone have the answer about how to deal with this kind of classes? (I read lots of documents by Hitz and Montazeri but I probably miss some)

If there's no answer about it, can we improve the way of calculating the LCOM4 to make it closer to the number of responsabilities of a class?

BTW, my case about this is in PHP, but I think this issue concerns also all others OOP languages.

Thank you guys,

Comment: After reading that page, I have to say that I think `LCOM4=1` is the correct answer. Based on the definition: "Methods a and b are related if:
(1)they both access the same class-level variable, or
(2)a calls b, or b calls a." To me, that example fits in the second case. I don't know how much of the OOP languages are covered by these definitions. I think at least for `LCOM4` they specifically mention `VB`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What I think is also that in this case, `LCOM4=1` but it is our opinions and it's not confirmed by any research or any document that explain this specific case. It might be a reason to consider my case different than the second point you explained that it is a new instance of the same class, but not the same instance we're linking. But you're right, `LCOM` is a **class** measure, not an **instance** measure, so we may consider `LCOM4=1`. I would like to have other opinions on this.

Comment: @niconoe, it is convenient to split this question into two parts. 1) how is LCOM4 calculated? (here we may get answers from the referenced papers (IMO you understand this metric correctly, I would say `LCOM4` here is `1`) 2) actual implementation of `LCOM4` calculation for the particular programming language. Implementations may see things differently, have defects, etc.. but that's ok. Real world always has its own constraints. We simply shouldn't follow this metric blindly. It may produce false positives but also it can direct your analysis and automated search of the "hot spots" :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you supplied:

> In addition to this mere formal improvement of the definition
>   of LCOM, we would like to get rid of a more semantic
>   flaws in the definition of LCOM: Firstly, the not uncommon
>   design principle to restrict accesses to instance variables to
>   special purpose read/write methods introduces an anomaly of
>   this measure: An otherwise cohesive class would yield very
>   high LCOM-values, **as all of the “real” methods would yield
>   isolated nodes in the graph, as they do not directly share any
>   instance variable anymore**.

I interpret that as the static method and the instance method is separated and thus are the overall LCOM4 = 2. That result is supported by the definition:

> They define Lack of Cohesion in Methods (LCOM) as the number
>   of pairs of methods operating on disjoint sets of instance variables,
>   reduced by the number of method pairs acting on at least one shared instance variable.

In your case that is LCOM4 = 1 + 1 - 0 = 2 as stated above.

Comment: I'm not sure about your 1st paragraph. To me, what the paragraph is saying is: all accessors are ignored but be carefull with links like `f1()` calling `getA()` linked to `a` and `f2()` linked to `a` also: ignoring the gettor would result in an `LCOM4 = 2` because `f1()` ("real" method) would be isolated while in fact, it is related to `a` just like `f2()`. Accessors still must being ignored but the `LCOM4` must still be `1`.
IMO, your answer doesn't respond to my question because, even if it's about the specifications on LCOM4, there is a lack of documentation in regards of my case.

Comment: You asked for an answer, and if you don't like the answer you shouldn't ask questions in the first place. I will not argue about my answer as it stands, e.g LCOM4 = 2, if you think you want changes how the process is conducted, I am not the correct person to talk to.

Comment: I'm not saying I want to change the process, I'm saying I want to understand how the process is conducted regarding the snippet I provided in my question. 
After reading the documentation part you enlighted to me, all I can say is it's not talking about my issue but it refers to another problem (already solved, by the way) in the `LCOM4` calculation.